Father starts relationship with son's girlfriend
Well it's an old movie. probably late 80's or early 90's. Key things I remember are as follows:
There is mom, dad and son. Son has a girlfriend. Dad and son's girlfriend start to get close and they have sex while they are visiting a historical arena like place. (Similar to colosseum or may be even it was) and then in another scene mom in the bed naked in a hotel room. room service brings things and after the servant left the son emerges under the bed sheets also naked and they are like making up (don't remember the plot exactly but may be son is making it with his mom to revenge his father making it with his girlfriend).
It might be an Italian movie although not sure about that.

Maybe Damage (1992)? A British-French film directed by Louis Malle and starring Jeremy Irons, Juliette Binoche, and Miranda Richardson. Based on a novel of the same name.

Dr. Stephen Fleming, a British cabinet minister, lives a pleasant life
  with his wife Ingrid and young daughter Sally. His older son, Martyn,
  is a rising journalist. At a party, Stephen meets a young half-French
  woman named Anna Barton, who introduces herself as a close friend of
  Martyn's; it is apparent, however, that Stephen and Anna are instantly
  attracted to each other. When Martyn visits his parents in London, he
  brings Anna with him, revealing that they are romantically involved.
  The sexual tension between Stephen and Anna is clear, though their
  partners are oblivious of this. Despite her relationship with Martyn,
  Anna arranges a tryst with Stephen at her apartment.
Stephen's obsession with Anna deepens. After an international summit
  adjourns in Brussels, he travels to Paris to meet her instead of going
  home. While Martyn is sleeping in a Paris hotel room, Stephen and Anna
  have sex in an open doorway in broad daylight. Afterwards, Stephen
  checks into a hotel across the street from Anna and Martyn's, spying
  on the couple through his window. Eventually, his infatuation reaches
  a point where he desires to be with Anna permanently, even at the risk
  of destroying his relationship with his son. Anna dissuades Stephen
  from doing this, assuring him that as long as she is with Martyn, he
  will always have access to her.
During a visit to Anna's apartment, Stephen finds that another man
  named Peter is already present. Peter — unaware of Stephen's affair
  with Anna — tells him that they are former lovers. A jealous Stephen
  initially assumes that Anna is cheating on him and, when Peter leaves,
  confronts her. Anna denies carrying on with Peter, and then describes
  in detail the death of her brother, who had committed suicide after
  expressing an incestuous desire for her. She recounts that she had
  compulsively slept with Peter in order to grieve over her brother's
  death, which she had witnessed. Stephen is placated by this
  explanation, and the couple once again have sex.
The Flemings travel to their country estate to celebrate Ingrid's
  birthday. During a meal there, Martyn announces his engagement to
  Anna, which visibly disturbs Stephen. That night, after Stephen
  receives oral sex from Anna, Sally catches them outside of Anna's
  room. Soon after, an anxious Stephen lies to Sally about what she saw,
  telling her that he was merely trying to console Anna about the
  upcoming marriage. Later, the Flemings have an awkward lunch with
  Anna's mother, who notices the awkward behavior between Anna and
  Stephen. She correctly deduces that they are having an affair and,
  during a car ride with Stephen, warns him to put an end to it.
Stephen initially complies and calls Anna to end their relationship.
  He tries to confess his misdeeds to both Martyn and Ingrid, but shies
  away from doing so both times. However, after Stephen succumbs to
  temptation and anonymously phones Anna's apartment, she mails him keys
  to a renovated flat where they can meet. When Anna visits his home,
  she tells Stephen that she could not marry Martyn without being with
  him. They go to the flat at an appointed time and begin another
  raucous tryst, but Martyn — having been guided to the flat by chance —
  finds them in bed together. Stunned, he falls over a stairway railing
  and plunges to his death. A devastated Stephen clutches Martyn's body
  while Anna silently leaves the scene.
Stephen's affair is exposed and becomes the subject of a media frenzy,
  with a mob of reporters convening outside his house. Inside, an
  anguished Ingrid reacts to the day's events by questioning whether he
  had ever been in love with her. It is strongly suggested that their
  marriage ends. Stephen, now publicly disgraced, is also forced to
  resign from his cabinet position. He meets Anna's mother at a hotel
  and finds that Anna is staying with her; they say nothing as they meet
  for the last time. Stephen withdraws himself from public life and
  retires to an unknown location in Europe. In narration, he reveals
  that Anna now has a child with Peter. In his flat, a photo of himself
  with Anna and Martyn, blown up to life size, hangs on his wall.

